How to use Apps script to move a lot of data rows at same time to different spreadsheet automatically base on time
I want to move data to another spreadsheet with a time limit, for example at 12PM the data will be moved automatically and then the data from the source will be deleted (I think by using triggers, but I don't know if it's true or not). For your information, previously I used checkbox but it was less efficient for me (script as below) because I have a lot of data that needs to be moved at the same time. Can anyone help me to make the script?. Thanks
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if(sh.getName()=='DatabaseTemp' && e.range.columnStart==13 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast('Access');
    e.range.setValue('FALSE');
    var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1qx-I_mv8Zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    var tsh=tss.getSheetByName('Database');
    var v=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()-3).getValues();
    Logger.log(v);
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,v.length,v[0].length).setValues(v);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}

enter image description here
An example of a sheet name is "Data Source" and the destination or target spreadsheet "1OWqOlqy_pfZXXXXXXxxxxxxx" with sheet name is "Database"

Are you familiar with getDataRange()?  and perhaps a method of  removing the header row. There's the bones of a good script (based on onEdit), I don't understand what is stopping you from modifying it. There appears to be some doubt about whether a time-driven trigger would do the job; have you done any reading/testing?

Automatically Move Data Between Spreadsheets Using Apps Script and Set Time-Driven Triggers
You can try this code:
function moveDataAutomatically() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data Source');
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1wWN8iocE0ZxII50P7p-vs8eReum3OAku6hdH3zmtW1I');
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Database');
  var data = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  if (data.length > 0) {
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    for (var i = sourceSheet.getLastRow(); i > 1; i--) {
      sourceSheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}

Here are the steps to set up a Trigger:
To run this script every day at 12 PM, you need to set up a trigger in Google Sheets:
1.) In the Apps Script editor, click on the clock icon on the left toolbar to open the triggers page.
2.) Click + Add Trigger at the bottom-right.
3.) Set the function to moveDataAutomatically.
4.) Set the deployment to Head.
5.) Choose "Time-driven" for the event source.
6.) Choose "Day timer" for the type of time-based trigger.
7.) Select the desired day and time for the trigger to run.
8.) Save the trigger, and your script will now run automatically once per day.
Additional image for visualizing the setup of Time driven triggers:

For hard-coded triggers, you can add this script.
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('moveDataAutomatically')
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1)
    .atHour(12)
    .create();
}

Sample Output:
Data Source

Database

Reference:
Time-driven triggers
Class ClockTriggerBuilder

Awesome, it worked. Thank you so much.

Is there a particular reason why the script deletes rows in a loop? Did you consider deleteRows or even Range:clear?

Thank you for your feedback @Tedinoz .There is no particular reason why the script deletes rows in a loop. I designed it to show the OP how the code works. I prefer to keep it that way to help the OP understand which part of the data the code is currently processing. I understand there is a faster way, and I was considering providing that option, but I want to avoid confusing the OP.
